# Trying to install Snow Leopard from .cdr but nothing happens after reload

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I am trying to upgrade from Tiger to Snow Leopard. I'm using a .cdr file on a USB drive to do the install

I'm prompted to restart the machine to continue the install, but nothing happens after the restart.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did the .cdr file come from, did you create it from the DVD? If yes then just use the DVD as you cannot upgrade a physical machine from Tiger to Snow Leopard using a .cdr file.

Comment: It's a borrowed drive, unfortunately. Shoot.

Answer (score 3):

Burn the contents of the .cdr image back to a DVD. To do this, insert blank DVD-R or DVD-RW, launch Disk Utility (located in the folder Applications > Utilities) and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>. Then select the .cdr file in the file selection dialog … That's the easiest way.

But if you have no Mac with DVD burner at hand, you will need to create a bootable USB flash drive (at least 8 GB capacity). You will have to use Disk Utility to first re-partition and format the flash drive with the 'GUID partition scheme' and the 'Mac OS X Extended (journaled)' format (HFS+, journaled). This makes the flash drive a bootable medium. Then use the Restore feature of Disk Utility to copy the contents of the .cdr image to the drive.

Alternatively, you can also buy the [Snow Leopard DVD](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) which Apple still sells  for $20.

See: [Starting from an external USB storage device (Intel-based Macs)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201663)